# The page options.php in wordpress gives 403 error

Tags: php, wordpress

The options.php file inside wp-admin which was working fine few days ago is now giving me 403 error suddenly. There was no change made and it gives me this error out of nowhere.

Here are few things I tried

1. Checking and regenerating .htaccess file.
2. Checking file permissions(wp-admin has 755 and options.php has 644) and ownership details which all seemed to be fine.
3. Deactivating and activating plugins one by one.
4. Checked user permissions in wordpress database. I made sure to have administrator role.

None of these helped me resolve the issue. It would be of great help if something can be suggested on solving this issue.
Note that I'm able to access other files within wp-admin folder except for options.php, Thanks.

Comment: 403 error for the `options.php` file indicates that you don't have permission to access the file. Check it's permission. Which should be writable by WordPress, which means the permissions should be set to `644` or `660`.
Also make sure that the `options.php` file is located in the correct location in your WordPress installation. It should be located in the `wp-admin` folder.

Comment: options.php is having 644 file permission and it is inside wp-admin folder, even then I'm getting 403 error. Is there anything else I could check on?